# Why =IF(10.1-10=0.1,TRUE) returns F in Google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, floating-point, google-sheets-formula, formula

What's the math behind this? Please explain. Thank you.

Comment: 10.1 - 10 == 0.09999999999999964

Comment: Because binary floating-point cannot  always represent decimal numbers exactly.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: And yet, `(10+0.1)=10.1` == `TRUE` ;)  *(Still, use integers, or use `ROUND()`)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned, it's a floating-point issue so to get TRUE out of it you should do:

```
=IF(ROUND(10.1-10, 1)=0.1, TRUE)
```

[image]